# Cross platform to-do app that meets exact requirements

Tags: cross-platform, analytics, task-management, todo

It would be great if someone could suggest a cross-platform (Windows/Web and Android, mainly) to-do app with additional features like:

- done tasks list(s) (with to-do tasks appearing there when done);
- labor input (how complex a task seems to be);
- priority level (importance);
- deadlines;
- auto sort tasks (on labor, priority, l+p average, deadline);
- custom tasks templates - like description, duration, tags, etc. - for tasks of common types like calls, meetings, conferences, chores, etc.;
- hotkeys (Android alike or widgets);
- extensive and detailed analytics - to-do vs done, overall per day, etc.
- Google suite sync is desired very much.

TUVM.